# Trying to add kml layer to google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I am working on a small web application that is using the Google maps java script API to display a map. I am passing in the html5 object of latitude and longitude to place a marker onto the map that displays the current location of the user. I have a kml layer that I am passing in as well. I am trying to display the current user location in relation to my kml layer. Well really I would just like the kml layer and the current user location both displayed. I have been trying to follow the google maps api to get this up and running. I was able to get the kml layer displayed in one test application and then I got the current user location displayed in another. When I attempted to combine the two the kml layer stopped displaying. This is a node js app using express js. I understand the kml layer element will not work on local host and I am deploying to a test location on heroku. Below I have included my relevant code:

```
<section id="wrapper">
Click the allow button to let the browser find your location.
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYGOOGLEMAPDEVKEY&sensor=true"> </script>

</article>
<script>
function success(position) {
var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';
mapcanvas.style.width = '600px';

document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
var centerLL = new google.maps.LatLng(33.439346,-86.88312500000001);
var options = {
zoom: 15,
center: centerLL,
mapTypeControl: false,
navigationControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
},
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options); 
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: coords,
  map: map,
  title:"You are here!"
});

var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: 'https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zrvhKWbQZI6E.kyr3RvQ9DprE'
});
georssLayer.setMap(map);
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
error('Geo Location is not supported');
}

</script>
</section>
```

Thank you for your time in advance.

Sincerely,
Fredk

**EDIT: I changed the src script tags to remove error I was getting on console about having too many google api src's**

Comment: Does the console have any errors?

Comment: Yes and you are brilliant. I just checked and this is the response I am getting:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://rmpgps.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. I am going to begin to look into it immediately but as always any more advice would be appreciated but thank you so much I cannot believe I didn't check console logs.

Comment: [The Google Maps Javascript API v3 thinks your KML is invalid](http://jsfiddle.net/ehhfco31/) as does [the KML Feed Validator](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fd%2Fedit%3Fmid%3DzrvhKWbQZI6E.kyr3RvQ9DprE)

Comment: How can you tell that google maps thinks it is invalid? I have another application that is using the same kml I am trying to use in this one and it works I can provide you with the src code if you would like to view it. Also @Mr. Concolato I have updated the code to where it currently has no console errors and works fine other than it is still not displaying my kml layer over the top. I will include the updated code above.

Comment: Hi @GeoCodeZip I tried to used your jsfiddle and load my kml into the feed validator and neither worked. [Here is the jsfiddle containing my code](http://jsfiddle.net/ehhfco31/3/) . I am using that exact code on a application I have in production at www.rmpdev.herokuapps.com where it is loading in the kml file properly. I copied the function from my src code there and tried to run in the fiddle and was unsuccessful. Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: The KmlStatus returned is "INVALID_DOCUMENT".  If you follow the link in my comment to the KML Feed Validator, you can see the "source" and why it thinks it is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong URL.

This is a map: https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zrvhKWbQZI6E.kyr3RvQ9DprE

If I download the KML (and choose the option "Keep up to date with network link KML (only useable online); the link in there is:

http://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zrvhKWbQZI6E.kyr3RvQ9DprE&lid=zrvhKWbQZI6E.kNpsmD-YyCYc

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: 'http://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zrvhKWbQZI6E.kyr3RvQ9DprE&amp;lid=zrvhKWbQZI6E.kNpsmD-YyCYc'
});
georssLayer.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(georssLayer, 'status_changed', function(){
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = georssLayer.getStatus();
    });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

[Include that as the URL for the KmlLayer and it works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ehhfco31/1/)

working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
url: 'http://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zrvhKWbQZI6E.kyr3RvQ9DprE&amp;lid=zrvhKWbQZI6E.kNpsmD-YyCYc'
});
georssLayer.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(georssLayer, 'status_changed', function(){
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = georssLayer.getStatus();
    });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks man this worked you are correct. I was using the wrong link. Thank you so much.